# Updating Python 2 code for suitable output

Tags: python, web-scraping

I had some Python 2 code as follows (pardon the indentation):

```
def getZacksRating(symbol):

c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.zacks.com")
c.request("GET", "/stock/quote/"+symbol)
response = c.getresponse()
data = response.read()
ratingPart = data.split('<p class="rank_view">')[1]
result = ratingPart.partition("<span")[0].strip()
return result

print getZacksRating("AAPL")
```

I changed it to (adding the b' ').

```
import http

def getZacksRating(symbol):

    c = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.zacks.com")
    c.request("GET", "/stock/quote/"+symbol)
    response = c.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    ratingPart = data.split(b'<p class="rank_view">')[1]
    result = ratingPart.partition(b"<span")[0].strip()
    return result

print(getZacksRating('AAPL'))
```

The bad thing is it's getting printed as

```
print(getZacksRating('AAPL'))
b'Strong Buy'
```

I don't wish to see the `b' '` in the output. Just want to see `Strong Buy` being printed. Not very familiar with Python, hence any tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return result`, use `return result.decode('utf-8')`